# golang pkg/errors How to print custom wrapped errors?

Tags: go, error-handling

My project wraps a custom error type `errNotFound`, which has an error embedded in it.
Now I have a [pkg/errors](https://github.com/pkg/errors) package that generates an error that prints the call stack. But when I inline this error into errNotFound, the call stack is not printed. Here is a sample, how can I change it?

simple:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    stderrors "errors"
    "github.com/pkg/errors"
)

func findSomething() error {
    return errors.Errorf("something not found")
}

func main() {
    err := findSomething()
    // can print error stack
    exitf("Error1: %+v", err)

    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println()
    // cannot print error stack
    err = ErrNotFound(err)
    exitf("Error2: %+v", err)
}

func exitf(format string, args ...interface{}) {
    fmt.Printf(format, args...)

    //os.Exit(1)
}

type errNotFound struct{ error }

func ErrNotFound(err error) error {
    if err == nil || IsErrNotFound(err) {
        return err
    }

    return errNotFound{err}
}

func IsErrNotFound(err error) bool {
    return stderrors.As(err, &errNotFound{})
}
```

output:

```sh
$ go run main
Error1: something not found
main.findSomething
        /home/lianxm/github.com/play_error/main.go:11
main.main
        /home/lianxm/github.com/play_error/main.go:15
runtime.main
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:255
runtime.goexit
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1581

Error2: something not found
```

I know I can get the original error by `err = errors.Unwrap(err)` and then print it, but this means that I need to do this every time before printing, which is not very elegant code, and I don't really want to do that...

here is an example project: https://github.com/lianxmfor/play_error

Comment: maybe `errorNotFound` implement [fmt.Formatter](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Formatter) can solve this, but i cannot how to implement the interface 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this necessary to put an error inside another if you already have your stack?

If yes... You can define a Method for errNotFound like:

```
func (e errNotFound) Error() string {
    return fmt.Printf("NotFound: %+v", e.err)
}
```

Comment: Yes, I need to put the error in errNotFound, which is very useful for me, see here: https://go.dev/play/p/VNJBWfbhhQZ

Comment: This method solves my problem, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you need to annotate the error with stack:

```
func ErrNotFound(err error) error {
        if err == nil || IsErrNotFound(err) {
                return err
        }

        return errors.WithStack(errNotFound{err})
}
```

Comment: Yes, I can do that, thank you! But that would print out multiple call stacks, which I don't really want to do.

Answer (score 0):

while calling `exitf` you can use [errors.WithStack](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/pkg/errors#WithStack) to print stack trace.

Comment: This has the same effect as calling `errors.Unwrap` before each `exitf `call, which I don't really want to do, it's not very elegant